# Connecting to Sharepoint Online and unlocking "locked" documents

Tags: document-library, powershell

Im trying to create a script to connect to our O365 SharePoint site and unlock documents which seem to think they are locked for editing. I was wondering if anyone could help as I know its achievable with an on prem SharePoint server

```
Connect-MSolService -Credential $credential
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking

#Variables for Web and File URLs
$WebURL = Read-host "Please Enter Website URL"
$FileURL = Read-Host "Please Enter File URL"

#Get Web and File Objects
$web = Get-SPOSite -Identity $WebURL
$File = $web.GetFile($FileURL)

#Check if File is locked
if ($File.LockId -ne $null)
Write-host "File is Loked out by:" $File.LockedByUser.LoginName
Write-host "File Lock Type: "$file.LockType
Write-host "File Locked On: "$file.LockedDate
Write-host "File Lock Expires on: "$file.LockExpires

#To Release the lock, Uncomment below lines:
#$File.ReleaseLock($File.LockId)
#Write-host "Released the lock!"
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you cant do this on sharepoint online.